# Add map parts to existing map

Tags: geoprocessing, okmap

I have 4 scanned maps in geotiff format and need to create a single map using OkMap with the 4 geotiff files.

How can I add adicional map files to a single map using OkMap?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You have a tag for OkMap but make no mention of that in your question body.  Are you using it?

Comment: First, You have to georeference maps.

Comment: The maps are all georeferenced. I just can't find an option that allows me to insert a new map/file on the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. As an approach, I joined the 4 geotiff's into one single Geotiff using GeoViewer from Lizardtech and export this one as a high resolution Geotiff. Now I am abble to work on this final Geotiff as desired on OkMap software.